# Chaquopy How can import .so in python file

Tags: python, android, chaquopy

android build is successful,but throws error at runtime.

`so` and `python` file path is app\src\main\python.

1.`so` file path change to app\src\main\jniLibs\arm64-v8a or app\src\main\assets also have the same errors.

2.in python file change `so` file path ,use /sdcard/FaceDetect/python/andoir.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so also have the same errors.

I use chaquopy. how to use so file in python file? where should the `so` file be set?

thanks!
python file detect.py:

```
from ctypes import cdll
import os

def detectImg(img_path):
    print("yxq-python::::" + img_path)
    print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    # cur = cdll.LoadLibrary('/sdcard/FaceDetect/python/andoir.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so')
    cur = cdll.LoadLibrary('./andoir.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so')
    model_path = "/sdcard/FaceDetect/python/sfd_face.pth"
    cur.diaoyong(img_path, model_path)
```

error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.boyun.hisensetestheadcount, PID: 1642
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.boyun.hisensetestheadcount/com.boyun.hisensetestheadcount.MainActivity}: com.chaquo.python.PyException: OSError: dlopen failed: library "./andoir.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" not found
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2671)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
    Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: OSError: dlopen failed: library "./andoir.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" not found
    at <python>.ctypes.__init__(__init__.py:348)
    at <python>.ctypes.LoadLibrary(__init__.py:426)
    at <python>.detect.detectImg(detect.py:9)
    at <python>.chaquopy_java.call(chaquopy_java.pyx:283)
    at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_PyObject_callAttrThrows(chaquopy_java.pyx:255)
    at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrows(Native Method)
    at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttr(PyObject.java:207)
    at com.boyun.hisensetestheadcount.MainActivity.detectImg(MainActivity.java:245)
    at com.boyun.hisensetestheadcount.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6709)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
```

Comment: What is this file `andoir.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, and where did you get it from? You won't be able to take .so files built for Linux x86_64 and load them on Android: the operating system libraries and processor architecture are different.

Comment: the so file is algorithm package maked by python .

Comment: the so file is algorithm package maked by python . Algorithm Engineer pack python file to so file, i use the method of so file in android.    is Android not a linux system ? android can not use the compiled so file for linux x64 system?

Comment: Unfortunately it can't, for the reasons I mentioned above. However, if you want to build your own native Python modules for Android, we (the developers of Chaquopy) may be able to provide you with some tools for that. If you're interested, please [contact us](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/contact/) with details of your situation.

Answer (score 1):

i use the follows code to get so file successfully.

Thank you mhsmith for answering my question.

And i found pytorch can direct used in android system,
click thishttps://pytorch.org/mobile/android/

i put the so file in assets package, and i use the method in the following code to get .so file in python file.

Because the so file given by the algorithm engineer is not build for Android system,so when i run the app with the errors like this:

```
Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: OSError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.boyun.hisensetestheadcount/files/andoir.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" has unexpected e_machine: 62
```

the metohd get so file path in android system:

java code call python:

```
void detectImg(){
    Python py = Python.getInstance();
    String soPath = assetFilePath(this,"andoir.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so");
    py.getModule("detect").callAttr("detectImg2", "/storage/emulated/0/FaceImg/star/timg.jpg",soPath);
}
```

python file:

```
def detectImg2(img_path,so_path):
    print("yxq-python::::" + img_path)
    print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    # cur = cdll.LoadLibrary('/sdcard/FaceDetect/python/andoir.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so')
    cur = cdll.LoadLibrary(so_path)
    model_path = "/sdcard/FaceDetect/python/sfd_face.pth"
    cur.diaoyong(img_path, model_path)
```

get so file path in android system.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
public class Utils {
public static String assetFilePath(Context context, String assetName) {
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), assetName);
    try (InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(assetName)) {
            try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
                int read;
                while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                os.flush();
            }
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("pytorchandroid", "Error process asset " + assetName + " to file path");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```